# Parameterize MySQL workbench statements: How to define variables

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to parameterize a set of frequently used queries in my workbench.

This works:

```
select * from providers where id='112233';
```

This

```
WbVarDef var1=112233;

select * from providers where id='$[var1]';
```

gives error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'from providers where id='112233'' at line 1

My reference was [this](http://www.sql-workbench.net/manual/using-variables.html).

Just to be clear, these are in the MySQL workbench and not a workbench script file or a mysql script file.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In MySQL, syntax for setting variable is below.

```
SET @var1 = '112233';
```

and using the variable would be as below.

```
select * from providers where id=@var1;
```

Check out MySQL documentation for more information [Link to MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set-statement.html)

Comment: To be clear, this has nothing to do with Workbench specifically. It's a regular MySQL syntax/feature that can be used by any application accessing the database. It is often used in triggers and procedures.

Comment: yes, this is a mysql syntax. Nothing to do with workbench

Answer (score 4):

Based on your tag `mysql-workbench`, I find it simply to be a case where the referenced documentation and use is not relevant to what you are using.

Back up the hierarchy from your link to this http://www.sql-workbench.net/

and you will read:

> Please note that SQL Workbench/J has no relation to the product MySQL
>   Workbench which is maintained and owned by Oracle.  If you
>   are looking for MySQL Workbench support please contact Oracle.